# Proper way to refer to "this" view callback handlers (success or error) after save in Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, binding, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to refer to the view element via $(this.el) within a success or error callback on a Backbone model.

Example:

From within SomeViewClass (which extends Backbone.View),

```
@model.save({}, {
success: (model, response) ->
    ($ this.el).removeClass("editing")
})
```

However, I'm stuck at the fact that "this" doesn't refer to the SomeViewClass instance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using CoffeeScript, you can use a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to bind the current value of `this` to your function:

```
@model.save({}, {
    success: (model, response) =>
        ($ this.el).removeClass("editing")
})
```

If you were working in plain JavaScript, you'd usually use the standard `var self = this;` trick:

```
var self = this;
model.save({ }, {
    success: function(model, response) {
        $(self.el).removeClass("editing");
    }
});
```

Or, since you're using backbone.js (which requires underscore.js), you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to build your bound function.

If your callback was bigger or you wanted to use the same callback in multiple places, then [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) would be an option. You'd have to make the callback a named method though; but, if the callback was large you'd probably want to un-inline it anyway.

Comment: great answer! don't forget about `_.bindAll`, too